# Trying to set up a character model for pixel textures. I want some parts' vertices to align with their own rotated grids. Is this possible?

Tags: texturing, uv, pixel-art

So I have a character and he looks like this:
[image: One man army, Crunch Taylor!]

He is my first blender model and I made him with intent to give him pixel art styled textures similar to [Rich Edwards' pineapple smash crew models look.](https://www.richmakegame.com/?page_id=399) I didn't think to watch any online tutorials like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RQVAUaSUP-k) before modeling him. So I made it this far and now I have to make him line up with Notice the angled edges and stuff. So I need to adjust certain parts to line up with the grid, but I don't want to lose the position and angle that certain parts like his shoulder pauldrons, the positions of his finger blocks, or the front side bags on his belt. Is it possible to adjust these parts on a grid that is rotated like them, or should I just bite the bullet and take the blocks apart, adjust for and paint on the textures individually, and then reconstruct his shape with the finished parts? Am I too worried about messing up my model?

Comment: Honestly I'm pretty confused on what I am doing. I'm not sure if this question makes sense.

Comment: You might want to investigate custom transform orientations. Not sure this will work for you though. I'm pretty confused also. But it still would be good to know about, in case it helps. So consider looking into it.

Comment: One piece of advice is just to archive a copy of this model as it is.  You can always come back to it if you discover a better method.

Comment: That sounds good. I will do that and experiment around with it.